# Регулярное выражение для разделения строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
String fullName = ""город Москва";"799"";
String regex = "\"(.*?)([А-Я].+?)\";(\\d*)\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fullName);
if (matcher.matches()){
    String status = matcher.group(1);
    String name = matcher.group(2);
    String code = matcher.group(3);
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста с помощью РВ разделить город, Москва и код, пытаюсь получить по группам, но не выходит. Если fullName = "Воронеж", без статуса, то status оставить пустым

Comment: А `String fullName = \"(\\p{L}+)\\s+([А-Я][^\"]*)\";\"(\\d+)\";` подойдёт? Какая у вас тут проблема? Как выглядит строка с Воронежем?

Comment: вот так ""Воронеж";"136"

Comment: `String fullName = "\"(?:(\\p{L}+)\\s+)?([А-Я][^\"]*)\";\"(\\d+)\"";`? Хотя, скорее, поможет только перечисление типов местоположения, что-то вроде `String fullName = "\"(?:(село|деревня|город)\\s+)?([А-Я][^\"]*)\";\"(\\d+)\"";`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew спасибо, получилось вроде по вашему примеру, там этих видов поселков|сел|районов|... более 200, всех не перечислишь. Когда-нибудь надеюсь пойму это мастерство регулярок..

Comment: Думаю, что первое выражение не сработает в случае, если в названии населённого пункта два и более слов. Если город/село и т.д. всегда начинаются с маленькой буквы, надёжнее заменить `\\p{L}+` на `\\p{Ll}\\p{L}*`

Comment: да, всегда с маленькой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать

```
String fullName = "\"(?:(\\p{Ll}\\p{L}*)\\s+)?([А-Я][^\"]*)\";\"(\\d+)\"";
```

**Подробности**

- `\"` - двойная кавычка
- `(?:(\\p{Ll}\\p{L}*)\\s+)?` - опциональная группа:

  - `(\\p{Ll}\\p{L}*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: строчная буква, а потом 0+  любых букв
  - `\\s+` - 1+ пробельных символов
- `([А-Я][^\"]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: заглавная русская буква, а затем 0 и более символов, отличных от  двойной кавычки
- `\";\"` - двойная кавычка, `;`,  двойная кавычка
- `(\\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №3: одна и более цифр
- `\"` - двойная кавычка

Answer (score 0):

У вас обычная CSV строка. Используйте для отделения левой части от правой по знаку "точка с запятой" обычный [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)). Пример:

```
String[] s = fullName.split(";");
String name = s[0];
String code = s[1];
```

. Если хотите что-то более масштабное или массовое, то [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).